Should I retract my submission to a CS conference after finding a couple of errors in manuscript?
I spotted two errors in my submission post-deadline for the first round of review (the next and final round is a rebuttal round where we can address the reviewers' comments). The errors are as follows:

The abstract mentions a performance increase of 3.4x, whereas the results and the conclusion mention 3.8x (correct), and the absolute numbers also show 3.8x.
Two citations in my literature survey are described incorrectly. However, they are not used in the evaluation and, even after correction, would not be considered a valid comparison and would not be added to the evaluation.

I understand such errors can irritate some reviewers. I am looking for any advice on how to deal with this situation. I am unable to focus on my research in the meantime since I am panicking and overthinking about how my carelessness will undermine our positive results. How does one deal with this situation?

These would not be sufficient reasons to withdraw the paper.
Whether the errors will result in a rejection depends on the conference. Some get so many submissions that they need to be very selective. Since there is a rebuttal, you have a chance to set the record straight. You should do so, even if the reviewers do not catch your errors.
Your first error will generate some initial confusion, but it is more in the line of a typo. Those things should not happen, but they do.
Misrepresenting previous work can really irritate people, (especially if they are the "victim"), and, if noted, will lead people to be much more skeptical of your work. If it is more in the nature of a clerical error, it is much more forgivable. It is a bit concerning that you chose to include these citations but then state that they really do not contribute to your argument. However, this might just be the reason that none of the reviewers will check, unless they are very familiar with the matter at hand. After all, reviewers cannot devote an unlimited amount of time to a paper and will not be able to check everything. However, you should set the record straight in your rebuttal.
From the tenor of your question, you seem to be a graduate student relatively at the beginning of your career towards a Ph.D. Conference rejections happen to all of us and you better get used to them. Errors on submissions also happen. But what about your advisor? That person should be able to calm you down. Making stupid mistakes is also standard and the conference format with its strict deadlines contributes to it. Stop panicking and continue to work on your project. At this point, there is almost nothing you can do about it. You could, in theory, write to the PC chair(s), but that would put them in a dilemma of giving you preferential treatment if they allow you to update your submission or of giving the reviewers knowingly bad data. I am not sure whether I want to suggest to you to not try this or whether I should advise you strictly against it. However, withdrawing the paper now is not going to work well for the conference either. For all you and I know, it might be a valuable contribution after these errors are fixed. Authors are notoriously unreliable when it comes to the merits of a submission.

Thank you for your response and for putting things in perspective. To elaborate on the nature of the citations, they help describe the landscape of the overarching research space but are not directly comparable to my work. Regardless, I will try to make peace and move on.

I'm not in CS so I'm not super familiar with the differences between submitting a conference paper vs a journal paper.
But, assuming you can make some more revisions during the second round of review, the first mistake is a non issue - I would not even worry about it. A reviewer may mention it at which point you can just thank them for pointing out the error and fix it. If no one catches it, just mention that you fixed a typo when you submit the next revisions. This one is not a big deal.
You're second error confuses me a bit. It seems a bit bigger. When you say you described them incorrectly, it makes it sounds like you misinterpreted the original papers. But, with the correct interpretation, they do not change your results. Is that right?
If that is the case, I would be worried that a reviewer would consider the work amateurish and dismiss the whole thing. That might lead to an overly critical review/rejection. But, really, they may or may not pick up on the mistake. If they do, there is a pretty good chance they will just say that you misinterpreted it. Just admit you were wrong and correct the mistake. If they don't, just correct the citations and make a note that you did that.
Either way, I would just wait to see what happens. The worst thing that can happen is the paper gets rejected (which may or may not be a result of the mistakes). If you withdrawal it, you're just preventing your results from being published - so it's the same outcome but there is no chance to fix the manuscript and get it out there.

Yes, I am worried they will consider it amatuerish. I will wait and see what happens! thank you for the response!
